# End tag for "input" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Tags: w3c

this is the problem I found when I validate my site with w3c validator, please help.
[link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fplaytimes.freshegg.com%2F&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.654)

Comment: If only that was the only problem with that source ...

Answer (score 5):

For

```
<input>
```

tags, use

```
<input ... />
```

ie, end it with a

```
/>
```

instead of a

```
>
```